# sync only one latest updated document in pouchdb through couchbase sync gateway

Tags: couchbase, pouchdb, couchbase-sync-gateway

In my angular Js application I am fetching data from pouchdb synced with couchbase sync gateway.I have set **rev_limit** to 5 in sync gateway config file. while syncing in pouchdb through sync gateway all revisions of each document are getting synced in pouchdb,so size of pouchdb is increasing,I want to sync only latest document in pouch rather to sync all revisions.

Can you please help in this or please suggest me any improvment I need to do

Thanks

Comment: You could try auto-compaction. I used that on my local pouchdb database because I didn't need any history of changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this. 
Impose the compaction when you create DB

```
var db = new PouchDB('mydb', {auto_compaction: true});
```

Compact on demand

```
db.compact();
```